# Jooq Postgres Varying Bit

Tags: java, postgresql, bit, jooq

I am looking into Jooq and has struck something that I can find very little documentation for - none that really answers my question in all honesty.

What I want to do is to have a column in a table like
permissions varying bit(2000)  (Postgres 9.5+)

What Jooq however does with this, is to see it as a varchar...  which obviously is incorrect even at generation.  What is the shortest path to success on something like this.

Comment: Thanks for your question. I've removed the Kotlin part, as it's not really part of the question and not a good fit for Stack Overflow (which is a platform that avoids opinionated things). But feel free to re-raise the issue on the [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jooq-user). We're very open to discussion! Meanwhile, I'll reply to your PostgreSQL `varying bit` question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure anymore what the design decision for mapping PostgreSQL's [*"bit string"*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html) types to `java.lang.String` was. I don't even exclude an oversight on the fact that even if they're called *"bit strings"*, they're not really strings.

I suspect that the most fitting Java type to represent this is a `BitSet`. So, your ideal way forward would be to implement a [data type binding](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) of the form:

```java
public class VaryingBitBinding extends Binding<String, BitSet> {
    // ...
}
```

And implement it at the JDBC level. You can then hook this binding into your code generator:

```xml
<forcedType>
    <userType>java.util.BitSet</userType>
    <binding>com.example.VaryingBitBinding</binding>
    <types>varying\ bit</types>
</forcedType>
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas, do you think this is something that can/will be entertained with the shipped JOOQ distribution in future?

Comment: @user1210708: Yes, at some point: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5507

Comment: Old post, but seems the only one dealing with postgresql bit data type and jOOQ. Using a ```BitSetConverter extends AbstractConverter<String, BitSet>```, I'm still running into _PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: bit varying <> character varying_

Comment: @Simon: My answer recommends to use a binding, not a converter, because you probably need to be in control of how the bind variable is rendered and bound.

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder, missed that the first time round. Taking the example from [your link](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/) and basically using '::bit' in the sql() method works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

My class is work in progress, but with this I'm able to store a varying bit:

```
public class BitSetBinding implements Binding<String, BitSet> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public final void sql(final BindingSQLContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.render().visit(DSL.val(ctx.convert(converter()).value())).sql("::bit");
    }

    @Override
    public final void register(final BindingRegisterContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.VARCHAR);
    }

    @Override
    public final void set(final BindingSetStatementContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
        // this most likely won't work: ctx.statement().setString(ctx.index(), castToBit(convert(ctx.convert(converter()).value(),
        // String.class)));
    }

    @Override
    public final void set(final BindingSetSQLOutputContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    @Override
    public final void get(final BindingGetResultSetContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // Get a result set, ie. convert something like '00000000' to a BitSet
        final String fromDatabase = ctx.resultSet().getString(ctx.index());
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(fromDatabase);
    }

    @Override
    public final void get(final BindingGetStatementContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        ctx.convert(converter()).value(ctx.statement().getString(ctx.index()));
    }

    @Override
    public final void get(final BindingGetSQLInputContext<BitSet> ctx) throws SQLException {
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<String, BitSet> converter() {
        return new BitSetConverter();
    }

    /**
     * Converter referenced by jOOQ
     */
    private static class BitSetConverter extends AbstractConverter<String, BitSet> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public BitSetConverter() {
            super(String.class, BitSet.class);
        }

        @Override
        public BitSet from(final String databaseObject) {
            if (databaseObject == null) {
                return null;
            }
            final BitSet bs = new BitSet();
            int pos = databaseObject.indexOf('1');
            while (pos != -1) {
                bs.set(pos);
                pos = databaseObject.indexOf('1', pos + 1);
            }
            return bs;
        }

        @Override
        public String to(final BitSet userObject) {
            if (userObject == null) {
                return null;
            }
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int k = 0; k < userObject.length(); k++) {
                sb.append(userObject.get(k) ? '1' : '0');
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```